# XINERaMA&FAKEEXTN in linux

Tags: linux, fedora

what is the XINERaMA&FAKEEXTN in fedora or linux and what is the use of that..?

Answer (score 1):

This refers to a workaround for a bug in an old version of the Sun JDK. There is no need for it when using IcedTea.